# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function stmt_init() on null in /var/www/html/FW/access_check.php on line 87

Tags: php

Hi there i was looking everywhere people have similiar errors but nobody have the same with "Call to a member function stmt_init() on null" im looking for a solution im struggeling since days with that.
here the part of the code where the error appears

```
$stmt = $mySQLcon->stmt_init();
    $stmt->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $arrVicData[0], $typ, $arrVicData[1], $arrVicData[2], $arrVicData[3], $arrVicData[4],$arrVicData[5]);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt ->close();
```

and here the whole code of the file:

```
<?php
include("config.php");

function canAccess() {
    global $ip_block;
    global $host_block;
    global $ua_block;
    global $geo_block;
    global $lang_block;

    global $myTable_ips;
    global $myTable_uas;
    global $myTable_hosts;
    global $myTable_langs;
    global $myTable_countries;

    global $redirectTo;

    $access_ip = getIP();
    $access_ua = getUA();
    $access_host = getHostbyIP();
    $access_host2 = getHostbyClient();
    $access_host3 = getHostnameFromIP();
    $access_country = getCountry();
    $access_langs = getLangs();

    $access_data = array(time(), $access_ip, $access_host . ' | ' . $access_host2 . ' | ' . $access_host3, $access_ua, $access_country, $access_langs);

    if ($ip_block) {
        $blocked_ips = (array)getDataFromDB("ip", $myTable_ips);

        if (in_array($access_ip, $blocked_ips)) {
            addAccess($access_data, "wifi_lock");
            return null;
        }
    }

    if ($host_block) {
        $blocked_hosts = (array)getDataFromDB("host", $myTable_hosts);

        if (checkArr($access_host, $blocked_hosts) || checkArr($access_host2, $blocked_hosts) || checkArr($access_host3, $blocked_hosts)) {
            addAccess($access_data, "filter_drama");
            return null;
        }
    }

    if ($ua_block) {
        $blocked_uas = (array)getDataFromDB("useragent", $myTable_uas);

        if (checkArr($access_ua, $blocked_uas)) {
            addAccess($access_data, "transfer_within_a_station");
            return null;
        }
    }

    if ($geo_block) {
        $allowed_countries = (array)getDataFromDB("country", $myTable_countries);

        if (!in_array($access_country, $allowed_countries)) {
            addAccess($access_data, "location_on");
            return null;
        }
    }

    if ($lang_block) {
        $allowed_langs = (array)getDataFromDB("lang", $myTable_langs);

        if (!checkArr($access_langs, $allowed_langs)) {
            addAccess($access_data, "language");
            return null;
        }
    }

    addAccess($access_data, "check");
    return $redirectTo;
}

function addAccess($arrVicData, $typ) {
    global $mySQLcon;
    global $myTable_logs;


    $query = "INSERT INTO `$myTable_logs` 
                (`access_time`, `access_typ`, `access_ip`, `access_host`, `access_ua`, `access_country`, `access_lang`) 
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    $stmt = $mySQLcon->stmt_init();
    $stmt->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $arrVicData[0], $typ, $arrVicData[1], $arrVicData[2], $arrVicData[3], $arrVicData[4],$arrVicData[5]);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt ->close();
}

function getIP() {
    $ip = null;

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'];
    } else {
        if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        } else {
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        }
    }
    return $ip;
}

function getCountry() {
    $host = 'http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip={IP}';
    $countryName = null;

    $host = str_replace( '{IP}', getIP(), $host);
    $data = array();

    $response = fetch($host);
    $data = unserialize($response);
    $countryName = $data['geoplugin_countryName'];

    if (empty($countryName)) {
        $countryName = "empty";
    }

    return $countryName;
}

function getHostbyIP() {
    return gethostbyaddr(getIP());
}
function getHostbyClient() {
    return gethostname();
}
function getHostnameFromIP() {
    $host = 'http://ipinfo.io/{IP}/json';
    $hostname = "empty";

    $host = str_replace( '{IP}', getIP(), $host);
    $data = array();

    $response = fetch($host);
    $data = json_decode($response, true);

    if (isset($data['hostname'])) {
        $hostname = $data['hostname'];
    }

    return $hostname;
}

function getUA() {
    return $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
}
function getLangs() {
    return $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
}

function checkArr($haystack, $needle, $offset=0) {
    if(!is_array($needle)) $needle = array($needle);
    foreach($needle as $query) {
        if(strpos($haystack, trim($query), $offset) !== false) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
function fetch($host) {
    $randomUA = array("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0",
                      "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; E6653 Build/32.2.A.0.253) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.98 Mobile Safari/537.36",
                      "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; HTC One M9 Build/MRA58K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.98 Mobile Safari/537.36",
                      "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A372 Safari/604.1",
                      "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A5341f Safari/604.1",
                      "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows Phone 10.0; Android 6.0.1; Microsoft; RM-1152) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Mobile Safari/537.36 Edge/15.15254",
                      "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; Pixel C Build/NRD90M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/52.0.2743.98 Safari/537.36",
                      "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SHIELD Tablet K1 Build/MRA58K; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/55.0.2883.91 Safari/537.36",
                      "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.3; KFTHWI Build/KTU84M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Silk/47.1.79 like Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36",
                      "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 8172.45.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.64 Safari/537.36",
                      "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/601.3.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.2 Safari/601.3.9"
                      );
    $ua = $randomUA[rand(0, count($randomUA) -1)];

    if ( function_exists('curl_init') ) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ua);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);

    } else if ( ini_get('allow_url_fopen') ) {
        $response = file_get_contents($host, 'r');
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return $response;
}
function getDataFromDB($column, $table) {
    global $mySQLcon;
    $results_array = array();

    $query = "SELECT `$column` FROM `$table`";

    $stmt = $mySQLcon->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($id);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $results_array[] = $id;
    }

    return $results_array;
}
```

?>

thank you guys in advance!

Comment: are all the relevant files included by this point in processing? ie: the db connection especially?

Comment: It would point to `$mySQLcon` being null, but as RamRaider is suggesting, there are bits which we can't see how/what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

i think .. You can use mysqli_connect() or mysqli_init()
  or follow this link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.stmt-init.php